# Typescript how to make a fucntion optional when its passed via props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a function through props but I'd like it to be optional. However, if I try to make it optional in the props interface by putting a "?" in front of the function, it gives me this error:

`'propsFunction', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.`

Is there any way to make a function optional to pass via props?

```
interface Props {
  
  users: Array<User> | undefined;
  propsFunction(userTo:string): void;
}

const Component: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use arrow function syntax to define the type

```js
interface Props {
  users: Array<User> | undefined;
  propsFunction?: (userTo: string) => void;
}

const Component: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
```

Comment: You can use the optional syntax with the `users` property as well: `users?: User[]`

Comment: `propsFunction?(userTo: string): void;` works as well.

Comment: @jsejcksn note that an optional property is not the same as a union type which includes undefined. The former can be excluded from object literals, while the latter must explicitly be set to undefined.

Comment: @Mack Right. The former is typically the more ergonomic choice.